# Number of circles on vertices of a regular polygon

Tags: combinatorics, polygons

> How many unique circles can we draw on vertices of a $n$-sided regular polygon? To draw a circle, pick two distinct vertices. One is the center of the circle, and the other determines the radius.

Let $a(n)$ be the solution.

The maximal number of such circles we can draw on distinct pairs of $k$ arbitrary points gives an upper bound and should be equal to $2!\binom{k}{2}=k(k-1)$. That is, we know:

$$ a(n)\le n(n-1) $$

We can start counting $a(n)=0,2,3,8,10,18,21,32,36,50,\dots$ for $n=1,2,3,\dots$

[image]

But I'm not sure how to find a closed form for the sequence.

I searched [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C+3%2C+8%2C+10%2C+18%2C+21%2C+32%2C+36%2C+50%2C+55%2C+72%2C+78%2C+98%2C+105%2C+128%2C+136%2C+162%2C+171%2C+200%2C&sort=&language=&go=Search) and it appears it corresponds to a sequence with following closed form:

$$a(n)=n\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor$$

Can we prove this?

Comment: This was a [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider drawing circles centered at point $P$ to all other points. If we pick some point $Q$ such that there are $k$ points between $P,Q$ when walking along the polygon **clockwise**, then this is the same as picking $Q'$ such that there are $k$ points between $P,Q'$ when walking along the polygon **anticlockwise**.

- If $n$ is odd, this means that exactly half circles drawn from some point $P$ will be duplicates.
- If $n$ is even, we have a point $Q^{*}$ which which is exactly opposite our point $P$ and does not have a corresponding "duplicate pair" point. In other words, if $n$ is even we have one less pair of duplicates but one more circle, per point.

Hence, we have:

$$\begin{align}
a(n)&=\begin{cases}
\left(\frac12(n-1)\right)n,&n\text{ is odd}\\
\left(\frac12(n-2)+1\right)n,&n\text{ is even}
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

Which can be simplified to:

$$
a(n)=n\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor
$$

Confirming the observations.

Comment: This was a [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) self-answer.